# Use the c:updateScreen local action to refresh a related list from a flow

Tags: lightning-aura-components, visual-workflow, visual-flows

Has anyone figured out how to use the [c:updateScreen](https://sites.google.com/view/flowunofficial/flow-local-actions/update-screen) component to refresh a related list from a flow?  Here is what I am trying to do:

1. Launch a flow from an Account page using the new Guided Action List Component
2. Have the user progress through the flow
3. At the end of the flow, create a case based on the user inputs in the flow
4. Use the updateScreen component from lightningflow.net to update the case related list on the original account page so the new case will be visible

I have added the updateScreen component to my flow as a local action, but I am not sure what my input or output variables should be.  I have tried both the account Id and the case Id, but no luck.  Unlike some of the other components on the lightning flow site, there is no documentation for this one.

Thx in advance for any help you can give.

Answer (score 2):

Change this component to use force:refreshView instead of using recordData, which I believe only includes the fields on the record. That would look something like this:

```
({
    invoke : function(component, event, helper) {        
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            $A.get("e.force:refreshView").fire();
            resolve();
        });
    }
})
```

There's no need to wait, so we "resolve" immediately and let the UI do its refresh. The component itself doesn't need the aura:attribute, design file, or force:recordData.